# Using class function arguments as path for xpath doesn't appear to work?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Here is the XML:

```
<Routes>
    <Route type="source">
        <Name>incoming</Name>
    <Table><Tablename>incoming</Tablename></Table>
    </Route>
    <Route type="dest">
        <Name>outgoing</Name>
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

My goal is to try to output "incoming" from Route/Table/Tablename, but use a class with a function.

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('routingConfig.xml', null, true);

class traverseXML
    {
    function getData($path = "Route", $type, $operation){
        global $doc;


        if($type == "table"){
            $path = $path."[1]/Table/Tablename";
            }

        if($operation == "value"){
            return $doc->xpath($path);
            }

        }   

        }
$traverseXML = new traverseXML;
```

I would have thought this returns a value, but it returns an array:

```
echo $traverseXML->getData("Route", "table", "value");  
//returns: Array
```

If I do this instead:

```
print_r($traverseXML->getData("Route", "table", "value"));
//returns: Array ( )
```

Why is it returning an array instead of a value?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: `[0]` should be `[1]` (the positions are 1-based, not 0-based). Also, your XML is broken as it should end with `</Routes>`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - it actually still does the same thing.

Comment: It doesn't return an empty array for me. http://viperpad.com/aNgLj7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) returns an array, which contains the found items (even if there is just one).  If you don't want an array, alter your function to look at the results returned from the XPath query and return whatever it is that you need.

For example,

```
    if ($operation == "value") {
        $results = $doc->xpath($path);

        if (empty($results)) {
            return NULL;
        }

        return (string) $results[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that XPath returns a node-set - i.e. a list of all nodes matching the expression. In this specific case there is only one matching node, but because that XPath returns in principle a list I assume that this is mapped in an array in PHP.

Try using an XPath like

```
string(Route[1]/Table/Tablename)
```

that uses the XPath standard function `string()` to convert the node-set into a single string  - this should give you a value.

Comment: Could you elaborate? `string()` isn't a function? I tried to follow the outline shown here: http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/handling-xml-data, they just use echo `$parent->child` to get the value.

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit, but I don't have much to add. I have no specific experience with PHP, but I would definitely expect an array or some other form of enumeration as result to that XPath.

Comment: ...reading the page you linked: 'You can of course use any valid XPath query. The method will always return an array'. They indeed use `$echo ...` but inside a `foreach` loop on the array. The `$parent->child` example is not using XPaths, is navigating directly the DOM